# Replacing digits in PowerShell doesn't work

Tags: regex, powershell

**Edit**: though the question above is related, this isn't the same question as asking the difference between `.replace` and `-replace`, nor does it have the same answer.

Per the [Powershell docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.powershell.aspx)

> `\d` matches any digit character.

I have a command (`gg`, an alias for `git grep`) that gives the output:

```
packages/somemodule/index.js:69:                 log(`woo`)
```

I'm familiar with regexs, and would like to change the output to :

```
packages/somemodule/index.js:69                  log(`woo`)
```

I.e. adding a space after the first digits and the colon (if you're interested, this is to make the file openable by an editor). However **a digit, one or more times, followed by a colon** `\d+:` doesn't work:

```
gg 'No previous' | % {$_.replace("\d+:",'xxxx')}
```

Trying different versions, [the \d](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html) doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ``'packages/somemodule/index.js:69:                 log(`woo`)' -replace ':(\d+):', ':$1'``

Comment: Yep I ended up using `gg 'No previous' | % { $_ -replace '(\d+):','$1 ' }`

Comment: The question comes from a misunderstanding of the difference between replace and -replace. Yes, that is not the exact question you asked but both the answer here and there are rooted from the same. Dupes are good and this is not hurting anything.

Comment: @matt I guess it depends whether you think 'duplicate' means 'this answer from a different question also helps' (which is true) or 'this question is a duplicate' (which is false). I tend to think 'duplicate' means the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command output is treated as string data. In your code you are calling the `[String].Replace()` method which does not support regular expressions. For this to work as expected, you need to use PowerShell's `-replace` operator.

```
gg 'No previous' | % { $_ -replace '\d+:','xxxx' }
```

This approach will allow PowerShell to utilize regular expressions for string replacement!